# Permissions of a new User changed mine

Tags: 14.04, permissions, sudo, policykit

I have a pc which is running Linux Ubuntu 14.04 and few weeks ago a colleague of mine added him to the pc and since then I can do sudo something but I can't perform certain actions like:

- installing a new printer
- go to the System Folder
  etc.
  How can I solve this problem?

When, for example, I try to install a new printer I have the thing showed in this image:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kI9eg.png]

Comment: That particular dialog is for policykit permissions, not sudo.

Comment: I know. It was an example to tell you what is happening in my computer. I was working before adding my colleague username to the computer. Now it asks for his password. How is it possible if this computer is meant to be for me?

Comment: How was this user added? Did your uid change? Or group memberships?

Comment: I don't know if it changed but now I have something like that:

me@flylab:~$ id me

uid=650403(me) gid=29077(groupXXX) groups=29077(groupXXX)

me@flylab:~$ id colleague

uid=200328(colleague) gid=29077(groupXXX) groups=29077(groupXXX),27(sudo)

I see that there is a 27(sudo) on my colleague account.

Comment: I don't know if my uid changed or not, but can my colleague do something to fix this?

Comment: Since your colleague is a sudoer, sure. He can add you to the `sudo` group: `adduser me sudo`.

Comment: But what does that SUDO mean? because I am able to do sudo right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the what I can understand, this is the state of things:

- You were the original user, and probably have `sudo` privilege either by your username or by your other groups.
- But the PolicyKit privileges are still the default from Ubuntu (members of groups `sudo` and `admin`, and the `root` user). You can verify this: `sudo cat /etc/polkit-1/localauthority.conf.d/51-ubuntu-admin.conf` should give:

  ```
  [Configuration]
  AdminIdentities=unix-group:sudo;unix-group:admin
  ```

So if you add yourself back to the `sudo` group (or the `admin` group, if it exists), you'll gain the PolicyKit privileges as well:

```
sudo adduser $(whoami) sudo
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You explained me well and I solved my problem.